# gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'41')

Tags: python, gzip

I have a .gz file, which is definitely compressed. I ran "file <file_name>" to verify that it is not just a wrong extension on the file. I can perform gunzip on the file getting, which then decompresses perfectly and I can also run gzip to compress the file again. No error messages at all doing so.

But when running my script using the "with gzip.open" command, I constantly get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unzip.py", line 28, in <module>
    decompress_and_recompress(root_directory)
  File "unzip.py", line 15, in decompress_and_recompress
    decompressed_file.write(compressed_file.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 292, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 479, in read
    if not self._read_gzip_header():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 427, in _read_gzip_header
    raise BadGzipFile('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)
gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'41')
```

I'm currently using this script (as a test script) to see if I can use the "with gzip.open" command:

```
import gzip
import os

def decompress_and_recompress(root_directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_directory):
        your text`for file_name in files:
            print(file_name)
            if file_name.endswith("_reps.fa.gz"):
                original_file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
                temp_file_path = original_file_path[:-3]  

                # Decompress the file
                with gzip.open(original_file_path, 'rb') as compressed_file:
                    with open(temp_file_path, 'wb') as decompressed_file:
                        decompressed_file.write(compressed_file.read())

                # Recompress the file
                with open(temp_file_path, 'rb') as decompressed_file:
                    with gzip.open(original_file_path, 'wb') as compressed_file:
                        compressed_file.writelines(decompressed_file)

                # Remove the temporary decompressed file
                os.remove(temp_file_path)
                print(f"Recompressed: {original_file_path}")

root_directory = '/path/to/dir'
decompress_and_recompress(root_directory)
```

Do any of you have suggestions to why this is? I cannot seem to figure it out myself.

Comment: gunzip can handle zip files as well, are you sure the file you are looking at is a gzipped file and not a zipped file or something else?

Comment: Error suggests the file is not a valid gzip file (first two bytes should be `b'\037\213'` not `b'41'`. What are the first 10 bytes of the file (`open(original_file_path, "rb").read(10)`)?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat | I ran following command: "file 223210_reps.fa.gz"
And got: "223210_reps.fa.gz: gzip compressed data, was "223210_reps.fa", last modified: Mon Feb 12 14:54:08 2024, max compression, original size modulo 2^32 16821" 
So I'm assuming it's gzipped based on this. Am I wrong to assume this?

Comment: @AnnaKeishaBoateng and that is the exact same file you get an error with? Keep in mind you are walking over a directory and running that code on all files that have a name ending in "_reps.fa.gz"

Comment: @DanielB | The first 10 bytes are: b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\x101\xcae\x02\xff'
Is this a problem I can fix? If yes, how do I approach it?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat | Yes, that is the exact same file I'm having the error with. 
I know I'm running through multiple directories looking for files with a certain ending. Multiple files are creating this error, but this is the exact file I'm using on here to showcase the error :)

Comment: @AnnaKeishaBoateng that shouldn't be possible, the `b'41'` that you see in the error are the first two bytes of the file. The bytes you talk about don't match with that.

Comment: You're saying the the first two bytes are `b'\x1f\x8b`, but Python is saying that the first two bytes are `b'41'`. Those are _two different files_. You are having some sort of confusion identifying the file being read by your Python code.

Comment: @MarkAdler I'm (unfortunately) not mistaking the files (atleast I cannot see how). The path is specified within the script, and it cannot be pointing to another file (there is only 1 file per subdirectory with the ending ".fa.gz". I make it call out the file name it is currently working on, and that is the last file name printed before the error. 
Do you have any suggestions on how else to figure out if it is a wrong file?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I thought so too. But as mentioned in the comment above, I cannot see how it could point to another file. I specify the path myself, there's only 1 file per subdirectory with the ending ".fa.gz", and I make the program print the file name of the file it is currently working on. The file I'm using as an example is the last printed file name. Do you have suggestions to fixing this?

Comment: @AnnaKeishaBoateng its most likely that you are confusing the file paths. Try running just the `gzip.open()` part of your code with an **absolute file path** hardcoded in your code. Its either you mistaking the file paths or the code that you show us in not the actual code you are running. Also you are running `print(file_name)` but are you printing `original_file_path`? Given you're walking over a directory there could be files having the same name present in different sub-directories.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you. I am always using absolute file paths (hardcoded in my code), which is why it got me confused. I printed the absolute file path instead of file name, which then showed me that I have a file wrongly named in that folder. This might be the case for many of my folders then (I have more than 50.000, so it is impossible to go through manually). Thanks again. This solved my mystery, and created another lol. But this is more manageable.